# How to bind database data to Datagrid columns?

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, xaml

i am doing a silverlight project and i added a datagrid to it, i added `AutoGenerateColumns="True"` property and binded database table using `DataGrid.ItemSource property`in code behind , but it shows all the colums in the table , what i want is i want to disable headers in datagrid and make some colums and then bind the particular columns data to the database table colum, Please explain with XAML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For hiding datagrid header add follwoing property to datagrid

```
HeadersVisibility="None"
```

If you do not want to show all the items in datagrid then first set AutogenerateColumn property to false and then add following xaml i

```
 <my:DataGrid.Columns>
        <my:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Group}" Header="Group"></my:DataGridTextColumn>
        <my:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Name"></my:DataGridTextColumn>
        <my:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Quantity}" Header="Quantity"></my:DataGridTextColumn>
    </my:DataGrid.Columns>
```

**Update::How to add button**

```
<my:DataGridTemplateColumn>
  <my:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
    <StackPanel>
     <Button x:Name="UpdateButton" Content="Update" 
        Click="UpdateButton_Click"></Button>
    </StackPanel>
   </DataTemplate>
  </my:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
 </my:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: Thank you :) can you please tell me how to add a button in DatGrid

Comment: So by using TemplateColumn we can add any control to the data grid and TextColumn is used for Text or Binding Text ? and what is the difference between 'x:Name' and normal 'Name'